# C: Passing nested structure array to function

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char, structure

**Since I can't delete: This code works, but I messed up with loops in my code!**

What would be the way to pass such structure to function, so that **char array** would be changed by reference(real value)?

Structs look like this:

```
#define CMAX 20
typedef struct product_struct
{
    char name[CMAX];
    int code;
}product_struct;

typedef struct shop_struct
{
    prodcut_struct product[CMAX];
    int productCount;
}shop_struct;
```

The usual function declare doesn't do the trick:

```
void funct(shop_struct *shop);
```

Atleast it doesn't work when I try to copy something in there like this:

```
strcpy((shop + i)->product[j].name, someString);
```

This way, I can access the name **within** the function, but outside the value disappears. How should I fix this?

Example code:

```
struct_shop shop[10];
void funct(shop_struct *shop)
{
    (shop + 0)->product[0].code = 200; //This works!
    strcpy((shop + i)->product[j].name, someString); //This works'ish
}
printf("%d", shop[0].product[0].code); //This works!
printf("%s", shop[0].product[0].name); //This does not work!
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: What this means is that `shop` is probably *not* referring to a properly allocated `struct`.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I wrote my problem out in the post. This code is not working as intended. Yes it compiles, but it doesn't do what it's supposed to.

Comment: *"My code is not working as intended"* is not a useful problem statement. It's even less useful when so many details are missing from the code you posted. Read the entire page about MCVE, and post one. It's not just about compilability. You must have enough in the post so anyone could reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. Here's a working example:

```
#define CMAX 20
typedef struct product_struct
{
    char name[CMAX];
    int code;
} product_struct;

typedef struct shop_struct
{
    product_struct product[CMAX];
    int productCount;
} shop_struct;


void rename_at(int n, shop_struct* shop, char const* name)
{
    strncpy(shop->product[n].name, name, CMAX);
}

int main()
{
    shop_struct shop = {0};
    strcpy(shop.product[0].name, "product0");
    puts(shop.product[0].name); //prints product0
    rename_at(0,&shop,"new_product0");
    puts(shop.product[0].name); //prints new_product0


}
```

Comment: It does. `strncpy` is a `strcpy` with a length check, but nothing's stopping you from using the unchecked `strcpy` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I just found out that I'm an massive idiot who can't deal with loops, so my problem wasn't the copying afterall... Sorry if I wasted your time.